# Filter different query fields from different forms

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in MS Access that pretty much has every data I need for different reports. I know how to filter the query from a combo box in a form, however, I can't do it from multiple forms. Let's say for one occasion I want to filter the query from one form but for another purpose, I want to filter the same query in a different field from another form. When I try it there is a window that pops up asking for the criteria in the other field. Bear me with my English is not my first language.

Respectfully

Comment: Please post the query. Then tell us which field in Q1 and which field in Q2.  Show us some sample data.  Then tell us what the expected result should be in each case.

Comment: I believe your query has references to form's fields. When this form is not open, query cannot access this field and asks about parameter

Comment: Don't use dynamic parameters that reference form controls. Use VBA to construct filter criteria and apply when opening report. Use the WHERE argument of OpenReport command. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Sergey S. You are absolutely right! Is this something that I must fix coding? I know a little about vba, but I was avoiding coding. Do you think it would be better to code this issue in SQL? If so, could you give me a good resource for to learn this language? I just don’t understand the sintaxis of the SQL.                        Very respectfully